# Filter an array with multiple conditions

Tags: javascript, arrays

Array looks like

```
products = [
    {
      "id": "5c94aa7b7a37631ce2a97a72",
      "material": "5c9485d37804946bc487ce59",
    },
    {
      "id": "5c94aa7b7a37631ce2a97a72",
      "material": "5c94862a7804946bc487ce5e",
    },
    {
      "id": "5c94aa7b7a37631ce2a97a72",
      "material": "5c9486397804946bc487ce61",
    },
    {
      "id": "5c94a0a87a37631ce2a979de",
      "material": "5c9485d37804946bc487ce59",
    },
    {
      "id": "5c94a0a87a37631ce2a979de",
      "material": "5c94862a7804946bc487ce5e",
    },
    {
      "id": "5c94a0a87a37631ce2a979de",
      "material": "5c9486397804946bc487ce61",
    }
  ]
```

and when I try to delete only one item with `id="5c94aa7b7a37631ce2a97a72"` and `material="5c9485d37804946bc487ce59"`

I use filter function

```
filtered = products.filter(x => x.id !== id && x.material !== material);
```

it removes all products with these ids and materials. What is the proper way to set conditions in this function?

Comment: maybe `products.filter(x => !(x.id == id && x.material == material))` ?

Comment: *it removes all products with these ids and materials.* then what do you expecting? in the result?

Comment: I'm seriously wondering why you have to ask how to write a condition in javascript, you should know this well before becoming a developer. And it smells like homeworks...

Answer (score 5):

Just use `||` instead of `&&`, so that *both* conditions must be false in order for the `filter` callback to return `false`:

```js
const products = [{
    "id": "5c94aa7b7a37631ce2a97a72",
    "material": "5c9485d37804946bc487ce59",
  },
  {
    "id": "5c94aa7b7a37631ce2a97a72",
    "material": "5c94862a7804946bc487ce5e",
  },
  {
    "id": "5c94aa7b7a37631ce2a97a72",
    "material": "5c9486397804946bc487ce61",
  },
  {
    "id": "5c94a0a87a37631ce2a979de",
    "material": "5c9485d37804946bc487ce59",
  },
  {
    "id": "5c94a0a87a37631ce2a979de",
    "material": "5c94862a7804946bc487ce5e",
  },
  {
    "id": "5c94a0a87a37631ce2a979de",
    "material": "5c9486397804946bc487ce61",
  }
];
console.log(products.length);
const id = "5c94aa7b7a37631ce2a97a72";
const material = "5c9485d37804946bc487ce59";
const filtered = products.filter(x => x.id !== id || x.material !== material);
console.log(filtered.length);
console.log(filtered);
```